# Primus + primus-rooms + sockjs: How to retrieve all clients connected to a room

Tags: sockjs, primus

I have a primus server that runs on the sockjs transformer. I'm using the primus-rooms plugin to support rooms. Joining and leaving rooms is successful, I can send messages to clients that are connected to specific rooms.

At some point I need to retrieve all the connected clients in a specific room. I want to use this: https://github.com/cayasso/primus-rooms#primusroomroomclientsfn

```
primus.room('room').clients(fn);
```

But the fn function always return null, even if there are clients connected to the room I'm targeting. This is my implementation:

```
var remoteRoom = 'the_room_I_need_to_target';
primus.room(remoteRoom).clients(function(clients){
    console.dir('primus clients in room ' + remoteRoom + ': ' + clients);
});
```

Do I need to configure something extra to get this to run? I'm thinking I need to configure an adapter for the rooms but I'm unsure what that does and how it should be done.

---

To be somewhat complete, this is my initial setup of Primus:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var Primus = require('primus');
var Rooms = require('primus-rooms');
var primus = new Primus(server, {transformer: 'sockjs', pathname: '/primus/my-room'});
primus.plugin('rooms', Rooms);
```

I can join and leave rooms successfully. Joining & leaving is triggered by some actions in the client:

```
primus.on('connection', function (spark) {
    spark.on('data', function(data) {

    data = data || {};

    var action = data.action;
    var roomToJoin = data.roomToJoin;

    if ('join' === action) { //join room
        spark.join(roomToJoin, function () {
            logger.debug('primus id ' + spark.id + ' joined room ' + roomToJoin);    
        });
    }else if ('leave' === action) { //leave room
        spark.leave(roomToJoin, function () {
            logger.debug('primus id ' + spark.id + ' left room ' + roomToJoin);

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler function is fn(error, clients) and not fn(clients). Changing the code to the following resulted in the expected behavior:

```
var remoteRoom = 'the_room_I_need_to_target';
primus.room(remoteRoom).clients(function(error, clients){
    console.dir('primus clients in room ' + remoteRoom + ': ' + clients);
});
```